# Быстрое копирование и расширение объектов ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, память

Какой есть наиболее быстрый способ скопировать один объект `ArrayBuffer` в другой? В частности, надо время от времени увеличивать размер буфера на определенную длину, что достигается посредством создания нового `ArrayBuffer` большей длины и копирования  него содержимого предыдущего `ArrayBuffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два способа расширить объект `ArrayBuffer`.

1. Копировать данные вручную через `DataView`.

```js
var ob = new ArrayBuffer(1024);
var nb = new ArrayBuffer(2048);
var nv = new DataView(nb);
var ov = new DataView(ob);

for (var i = 0; i < 1024; i += 8) {
    nv.setFloat64(i, ov.getFloat64(i));
}
```

Причем стоит заметить, что наиболее эффективно это будет если копировать по 8 байт через `getFloat64()`(выигрыш примерно в 8 раз по сравнению с побайтным копированием через `getUint8()`).

2. Воспользоваться типизированными массивами, созданными на основе `ArrayBuffer`.

```js
var ob = new ArrayBuffer(1024); // старый буфер
var nb = new ArrayBuffer(2048); // новый буфер
new Uint8Array(nb).set(new Uint8Array(ob)); // копируем через массивы
```

Тестирование обоих методов при копировании  массива размером 16 Мб (`new ArrayBuffer(16777216)`) в массив вдвое большей длины, дало следующие результаты:
первый метод занял 456 миллисекунд, а второй - примерно 11 миллисекунд.

Очевидно, что второй метод несравненно лучше.

Стоит отметить, [что было предложение](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/transfer) добавить метод `ArrayBuffer.transfer()` для целей расширения `ArrayBuffer`, но пока что оно развития не получило.

Идея расширения `ArrayBuffer` через типизированные массивы [взята отсюда.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100798/whats-the-most-straightforward-way-to-copy-an-arraybuffer-object)

---

**Обновление:**

Также можно использовать объект [WebAssembly.Memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Memory), у которого есть метод `grow()` для расширения внутреннего `ArrayBuffer`. Например:

```js
const pageSize = 64 * 1024;
const initialDesiredLength = 1000;
const memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({ 
   initial: Math.ceil(initialDesiredLength / pageSize), 
   maximum: 65536 
});

const buffer1 = memory.buffer;
let dataView = new DataView(memory.buffer); 

// выполняем любые операции

// увеличиваем буфер на 10 * 64 * 1024 байт
memory.grow(10);

// ссылка на старый буфер не работает, но данные сохранятся
console.log(buffer1.byteLength); // будет 0, поэтому
dataView = new DataView(memory.buffer); // пересоздаем DataView
```

Возможный минус этого способа в том, что `grow()` принимает только целое число страниц. Однако при работе с большими объектами это не играет роли. Преимущество же в том, что, как показывает практика, при работе с буфером размером около 1,5 Гб копирование через типизированный массив с высокой вероятностью приведет к превышению лимита памяти, и вкладка браузера упадет (так как в какой-то момент будет 2 буфера по 1,5+ Гб каждый). При вызове `grow()` такой проблемы не наблюдалось.